# Can the electroweak/strong forces, and/or quantum mechanics be thought of as geometric?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, geometry

Can the electroweak and strong forces be written as geometric theories? - Why and why not?

Can quantum mechanics in general?

For example, the Kaluza-Klein theory explains the electromagnetic field as "twists" that include an extra dimension of space. (As written by Lubos Motl in a previous question).

Comment: Well, I get the impression from reading your previous question that you would not call (the standard formulation of) the standard model geometric. What is your definition of a _geometrical theory?_ That it can be viewed as a higher-dimensional Kaluza-Klein theory?

Comment: @Qmechanic I suppose I mean any kind of geometric theory - something like the Kaluza-Klein theory in that the electromagnetic field is treated in a geometric way, but not necessarily that, and for more than just the electromagnetic field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Qmechanic's comment, maybe something like the noncommutative geometry approach would appeal to you. See e.g., [Noncommutative standard model on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_standard_model) and [Alain Conne's homepage](http://www.alainconnes.org/).

Comment: that looks interesting! Thanks, I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 4):

By "geometric" I'm going to assume that you mean "having to do with the geometry of the usual 3+1 dimensions", that is, geometric in the sense that electricity and magnetism is geometric.

This is a question that was researched deeply in the 1950s especially by Coleman and Mandula after which the "[Coleman-Mandula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Mandula_theorem)" theorem is named. As wikipedia puts it, "It states that "space-time and internal symmetries cannot be combined in any but a trivial way". Thus the internal symmetries are not related to "geometry" in the sense of our usual world.

The Coleman-Mandula theorem depends on a lot of complicated mathematics. One can imagine a bunch of ways that one could get around it. If you [google Coleman-Mandula](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22coleman-mandula%22%20site%3aarxiv.org&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) on arXiv.org, you can find papers on this subject, i.e. extensions and consequences of the Coleman-Mandula theorem, as well as papers proposing how one might get around it:

Comment: It would be nice to list the possible ways around it. E.g. Supersymmetry, noncommutative geometry, quantum groups, fields with no mass gap, ...